# Mule HTTPS request with Basic authentication

Tags: authentication, https, mule, httprequest, basic-authentication

I am trying to make an HTTPS request in Mule with Basic Authentication. For some reason I only have NTML and None as options in the HTTP connector.

So I tried adding the basic-authentication element to my request-config:

```
 <http:request-config name="Req_My" protocol="HTTPS" host="${my.host}" port="${my.port}"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
    <http:basic-authentication username="${my.user}" password="${my.password}" preemptive="true" />
</http:request-config>
```

But no Authorization header is set in the debug output.

I could always do a set Property (if I find out how to do a Mel Base64 encode) but according to the documentation the Basic authentication is standard functionality

Comment: I realize that a lot more security options aren't showing.

I don't have OAuth and OAuth2 either like showing in this example. I only have Basic and NTLM showing.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/authentication-in-http-requests

Comment: What version of Anypoint Studio are you using? Be sure to have the latest update.